# Php, new keys and values added inside loop dissapear outside loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops

For a school assignment I'm trying to split stockitems with product details like colour and size in the title into groups of stockitems with different variants. I've got as far as having them all split, but I just can't figure out how to add this information to the $stockItem array. ($stockItem is inside the array $stockItemGroup which is inside the array $stockItemGroups).

When I try to add information to the array inside the loop, I cannot access that information outside the loop. If I use print_r on the entire array after this loop has completed the new information is not displayed.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($stockItemGroup); $i++){
    $stockItem = $stockItemGroup[$i];
    $restString = str_replace($similarString, "", $stockItem['StockItemName']);
    $colour = getColour($restString, $allColours);
    $restVariant = getRestVariant($restString, $allColours);

    $stockItemGroup[$i]['Colour'] = $colour;
    $stockItemGroup[$i]['RestVariant'] = $restVariant;
    $stockItemGroup[$i]['NewItemName'] = createNewItemName($colour, $restVariant, $stockItem['StockItemName']);
}
```

I have tried both in a foreach and a for loop (I read that a foreach does some copying, so I thought that might cause it). but to no avail.

I have also obviously tried

```
$stockItem['Colour'] = $colour;
$stockItem['RestVariant'] = $restVariant;
$stockItem['NewItemName'] = createNewItemName($colour,
                                              $restVariant, 
                                              $stockItem['StockItemName']);
```

But that did not change anything either.

I am a total Php noob, so it might be very obvious, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
this loop is inside a method which is called in this loop:

```
$stockItemGroups = getStockItemGroups();
foreach ($stockItemGroups as $stockItemGroup){
    addVariants($stockItemGroup);
    //writeNewGroup($stockItemGroup);
}
```

Comment: Would you show us the complete loop, I get the feeling this is a loop inside another loop

Comment: It is inside a method(addVariants) that is called in a loop:

$stockItemGroups = getStockItemGroups();
    foreach ($stockItemGroups as $stockItemGroup){
        addVariants($stockItemGroup);
        //writeNewGroup($stockItemGroup);
    }

Comment: Please add the code directly in the question, **not** in the comments.

Comment: `foreach ($stockItemGroups as &$stockItemGroup){` Pass the array as a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach ($stockItemGroups as &$stockItemGroup){ Pass the array as a reference – RiggsFolly